# Prevent WPF 4.0 Datagrid from Showing Empty Column

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

[image]

I have an application with a datagrid with 1 column (for now). How do I remove the second, empty column from the datagrid such that only columns with data are displayed in the datagrid.

Comment: Probably you mean to set Width="*" ?

Comment: Do you want the column to consume all the available Width or do you want to hide the "empty column"?

Comment: I want the column to consume all available WIdth

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As vorrtex said in a comment the best thing to do is probably to set the column width to fill all available space:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FishLine ID" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Depending on the container you use you could also align the grid to the left side, leaving empty space to its right:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FishLine ID"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Hopefully that is what you were looking for...

Comment: Your answer didn't worked for me, instead I used the following DataGrid property definition, which worked for me: `RowHeaderWidth="0"`

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to False, and do something like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns = "False" ItemsSource = "{Binding BindSource}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "FishLine ID" Binding = "{Binding ID}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

That should do it :p

Answer (score 2):

If width of one column is "*" even then I've seen empty column at right of datagrid. To solve this, specify the Width of datagrid as "Width=500" instead of MinWidth and MaxWidth.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="500" MinHeight="180" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Date" Binding="{Binding StartDate}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="60" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Date" Binding="{Binding EndDate}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="60" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```